# Using MassEmailMessage is not saving EmailMessage records

Tags: apex, case, massemailmessage, emailmessage

I'm a developer, and I just did some work using MassEmailMessage on Case records (with the related Contact being the recipient). During testing I noticed that it's not saving any sort of EmailMessage record on the Case, only a Task record that isn't especially helpful with telling what was sent. I can't use SingleEmailMessage to send since that doesn't support being attached to a Case.

Is there a way to have a EmailMessage record be saved on the Case without making new records?

Comment: did you go through all of the [enhanced Email considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&type=5) (see bullet about Classic for example)

Comment: I have not, I will look into that now.

Comment: It looks like it's enabled, but it's still not saving the EmailMessage record. I've checked if any records have been created using SOQL, but no EmailMessage records have been created despite me doing testing today.

Comment: is the emailmessages related list included on the Case object?

Comment: It is, but the list is remaining empty.

Comment: well, i can reproduce your issue but don't have an answer (yet).  Maybe someone else on the Community has better experience here